# Phoenix says a schema doesn't have an association, even though I gave it one

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In the Phoenix tutorial section on Contexts (https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/contexts.html#cross-context-data) I'm getting this error:

[image]

It comes as a surprise because I added this association:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the line with

```
field :user_id, :id
```

Removing that line made it work.